# How to set up a start menu for logistics program in C?

Tags: c, menu

So I'm starting my final project for school and i have one small question. It is a logistics program that should be applied to a warehouse and run stock,deliveries,orders etc.
The user enters a command and then the variables of such command afterwards. For example, the command 'a' should add a new product to the warehouse. The input for this would be `a description:price:weight:qt`.
My idea for this would be having a start menu that only reads the command `a` and then redirects to a unique function that only takes care of the read command. Im kinda new to C so I would like to know the best way to implement this. 
Thanks for any help possible!

Comment: Your idea sounds fine. Ask the user for input and use a `switch` statement to select an action based on the input. Here's one example I found on SO: [Simple Option Menu (C)](//stackoverflow.com/q/33929671)

Comment: @JohnnyMopp the difference is the input in my program shouldn't include only the option (a,b,c etc.), it should include both the option and the arguments afterwards, while only reading the command first, then redirecting to the specific function and finally reading the rest of the input afterwards.

Comment: You can enter all the information for one transaction on one line. If you are using `scanf` it doesn't care whether the information is on one line or several (subject to dealing with leading whitespace with format specifiers `%c` and `%[...]`), or is read by a single statement, or by several.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `switch` statement.

```
char c = myInput[0];
switch(c)
{
    case 'a' : functionThatImplementsA(); break;
    case 'b' : functionThatImplementsB(); break;
}
```

Comment: I did not know about that switch command. Looks exactly like what iI needed. Very appreciated!